# Custom Forms Solution for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom, flow, online

Looking for feedback from the community. has anyone use a forms solution (3rd Party) that is not too expensive and can do following: (The PowerApps solution is coming out to be too expensive with the number is users)
- Create Custom forms
- Ability of do some branding
- Has capability to built calculated fields
- Can pull data from lookup list
- Can be saved as pdf
- has e-signature capability
- has password protection capability
- works great with MS Flow/Automate
thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OOB tools/ methods to customize form:

- InfoPath
- Custom .NET SharePoint Forms
- SharePoint Forms Designer

To get other third party tools for form solution, you can check the following articles:

[5 alternatives to InfoPath for SharePoint forms](https://sharegate.com/blog/5-alternatives-to-infopath-for-sharepoint-forms)

[Top Infopath Forms Replacements For Sharepoint](https://directory.collab365.community/office365-sharepoint/top-infopath-forms-replacements-for-sharepoint/)

[The Best Free Forms Solution for SharePoint](http://www.markrackley.net/2017/12/28/the-best-free-forms-solution-for-sharepoint/)

*Third Party Tool disclaimer:
While Microsoft supports and encourages open-source software development, it does not provide technical support for the softwares from third parties, nor does it guarantee that the software will work as described.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint online, the quickest and easiest solution is [Microsoft Office Forms](https://forms.office.com/).  It doesn't have a ton of branding/customization options, but it is quick and easy to get up and running and integrated with Power Automate (Flow).

On the other end of the complexity spectrum, you can create a custom list to hold the information you want, then develop an [SPFx custom webpart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) to control the input.  This could have a high initial development cost, but there are no additional per user recurring costs.  The data in your SharePoint list then has all the normal connectivity points to Power Automate.